# How to process big files in dart asyncronously in a performant way

Tags: dart

By using [File.openRead()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-io/File/openRead.html) Dart allows to read big files asyncronously in chunks of 64k Bytes. But as the chunks are of Type `List<int>` I doubt that this is a performant method.

There is a datatype [ByteBuffer()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html) which would probably be a perfect match for that requirement, as the data could be transferred directly from disk to memory.

But by returning a `List<int>` The file has to be read byte by byte and for every byte a 64bit integer object has to be created, that has to be appended to the list. So my question:

1. Is there an internal optimization to List to make it performant?
2. Or are there different methods for more efficiency?

Comment: Seems to use `Uint8List` internally as it should: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/f8878347837d2761602824de6fb5535ff1bbe0c0/sdk/lib/io/file_impl.dart#L12

Comment: Thx. I didn't know that ``Uint8List`` is a highly optimized implementation of ``List<int>``. If you write an "official" answer to my questions I will give it an up vote.

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is an internal optimization to do this. They use `Uint8List` so there isn't wasted memory like you said.

Source: [file_impl.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/f8878347837d2761602824de6fb5535ff1bbe0c0/sdk/lib/io/file_impl.dart#L12)